How do I fix this module error when attempting to launch mplab-x ipe 6.20 version?
enter image description here
I am receiving this error when trying to launch MPLAB IPE 6.20 after downloading MPLAB IDE 6.20. Does anyone know how I can fix this
I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Some other post said to clear the cache folder but I havent been able to find one applicable
